# C# Replace all elements of List<string> with the same pattern with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, lambda

I have a C# List with thousands of strings:

```
"2324343"
"6572332"
"45122" ...
```

I would like to replace all of them with brackets around them, so then they would look like

```
"(2324343)"
"(6572332)"
"(45122)" ...
```

I know how to write a for loop and do this but I would like to know if there is a way to do it with LINQ and LAMBDA expression preferably. I am open to other suggestions as well.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var resultList = list.Select(x => string.Format("({0})", x)).ToList();
```

Comment: If there really is thousands of strings, and all you want to do is place parenthesises around them, I wouldn't use `string.Format`, just use `'(' + x + ')'`. `string.Format` can be a beast as it handles A LOT of different formatting (and can even be extended).

Comment: @Alxandr  Have you benchmarked it? I've just did: for `10000000` strings `string.Format` took `5785` ms while  `'(' + x + ')'` took `4531` ms. I don't see any benefits, considering that your solution will create two strings for each input string, while  string.Format will create only one per input string. NOTE: `"(" + vals[i]  + ")"` performs in `2088` ms. This is probably due to a boxing issue of chars. Factor **3** is more like an improvement for me

Comment: Not personally no. I've just read documentation for loggin which strongly advices against using it for performance-reasons. Also, if the compiler is a fair amount of smart (which I asume it is), there will only be one string created both of the times (I highly doubt `(000` is created first than `(000)` (or the other way around), though I might be mistaken.

Comment: IIRC, placing `"(" + x + ")"` essentially converts it to a `String.Concat` call which is itself pretty efficient. EDIT: Just noticed the use of `char` with single quotes; I wouldn't do that personally; I just stick with strings. :)

Comment: @Alxandr see the **IL**, you would be surprised)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov with or without optimizations? Also, IL isn't the final answer, things JITed later. Though as said, you might be right. Also, for sports, try benching something like this: http://monobin.com/1574/ . I don't have VS (or windows for that matter) on my current PC, so I'm unable to do it self, but it'd be a fun comparison imho.

Comment: @Alxandr you have unfinished snippet. Use www.ideone.com to publish and launch C# code. This would be a very good evidence, even though it uses Mono clr.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I know. No IDE makes for difficult coding using method I never actually use :). Can you upload the code you used for your benchmark so I can add mine in a similar manner?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov 1. the compiler is smarter than me. 2. string.Format is 3 times as slow as `(` + x + `)`. http://ideone.com/DfyTpO I removed all LINQ so they all would stand on equal footing (without the overhead for method-calling etc.).

Comment: This "performance" discussion is one of the silliest things I've seen in a while, beginning with the first comment. It's highly unlikely that this code is going to be a bottleneck. So any time spent trying to optimize it is just wasted. And even though the "factor of 3" speed improvement seems impressive, we're talking perhaps four seconds for 10 million iterations. Nobody is going to notice a difference. Ever.

Comment: @JimMischel Assuming the time spent doing the conversion isn't visible to the user I agree completely.  However if the conversion occurs on a common codepath between the user clicking the parenthesize button and the application displaying a completion message even a tenth of a second is enough to matter.

Comment: I don't think @JimMischel's comment is useful, a few seconds is quite a long time and you have no idea what this is used for, it could well be a bottleneck.  Also, this discussion is providing more detailed information about a possible solution and is educational.  Just my humble opinion :)